# Wrapping futures with custom objects

Tags: scala, future

Is it possible in scala to add custom variables while creating futures (like some kind of context) that stick with the future task and is available throughout the task since futures are immutable once created so wanted to add those variables beforehand.

```
def mainAction() {
     //get that custom variable here
}
def doSomething() {
    mainAction()
}

def main() {
    Await.ready(Future(doSomething, add customVar here), Duration.inf)
}
```

I dont want to send these values through functional arguments as it's an application wide change and is not recommended. I am looking for a similar approach so that I can fetch the variables throughout the application whenever required

Comment: Can you clarify what the goal is? How/where do you expect to retrieve the value? In your code sample, a regular function argument would be enough.

Comment: "I don't want to ..." is not a good argument for any kind of engineering decision. And "is not recommended" is simply _wrong_ in this context. What is _really_ not recommended is exactly what you are trying to do: making your function depend on externally defined global state rather than its parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two approaches right now.

## Implicit Context Objects

This approach will make your life easier. You can define all you need in the `Context` `class`.

```scala
class Context(val value: Int)
```

Then, you can define an `implicit` value and use it.

```scala
def mainAction()(implicit context: Context) {
  println(context.value)
}

def doSomething()(implicit context: Context) {
  mainAction()
}

def main() {
  implicit val context: Context = new Context(1)
  Await.ready(Future(doSomething()), Duration.Inf)
}
```

## Config Module

You can also have some modules to load the configuration variable with respect to the environment.
To start with this approach, you should have a `Config` `trait` and `object`.

```scala
trait Config {
  val config = Config
}

object Config {
  val value = 1
}
```

I also changed your code to show how you can decouple functions.

```scala
def doSomething(){
  MainAction.mainAction()
}

def main() {
  Await.ready(Future(doSomething()), Duration.Inf)
}
```

And, you have the `MainAction` `object`.

```scala
object MainAction extends Config {
  def mainAction() {
    println(config.value)
  }
}
```

You can read more about this approach on my blog [post](https://saeiddadkhah.medium.com/clean-architecture-in-scala-41d1ab05a618).